# Writing a string to an OutputStream without using int onebyte

Tags: java, android, mysql, outputstream

This is a total beginner question, I've spent the past hour searching both stackoverflow and Google, but I haven't found what I'm looking for, hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to write a string to an OutputStream, which I will then use to write data to a MySQL database. I've successfully retrieved data from a MySQL (from a .php, implementing JSON and RESTful), so I have some idea of what I'm doing, I think. I'm creating a method which will take a string and return an output stream, and I'm having trouble writing to an output stream, because when I try to initialize one, it creates an anonymous inner class with the write(int oneByte) method. That's not what I want.

```
private static OutputStream convertStringtoStream(String string) {
    byte[] stringByte = string.getBytes();
    OutputStream os = new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
            /** I'd rather this method be something like
            public void write(byte[] bytes), but it requires int oneByte*/
        }
    };
    //return os here
}
```

As you can see, I want to write to my OutputStream with the buffer, not a single byte. I'm sure this is simple question, but I've not been able to find an answer, or even sample code which does what I want. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method could look like this, but I'm not sure what it would accomplish. How would you use the returned `OutputStream`?

```
private static OutputStream convertStringtoStream(String string) {
    byte[] stringByte = string.getBytes();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(string.length());
    bos.write(stringByte);
    return bos;
}
```

Also, note that using `String.getBytes()` might get you into trouble in the long run because it uses the system's default encoding. It's better to choose an explicit encoding and use the `String.getBytes(Charset)` method.

Comment: What I was planning on doing was sending that data to a php page, which would in turn decode it and write it to a MySQL db. Is this the wrong way of going about doing it? My ultimate goal with this whole thing is to write some data to a MySQL database from android. All the RESTful examples I've looked at are concerned with retrieving data, but not writing data. Do you know of a different/better way to achieve this?

Edit: My browser wasn't displaying my comment for some reason, I thought it didn't go through so I tried to repost, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like you're trying to construct a HTTP request that will send the string to your PHP page. I'm not too familiar with REST, but have a look at the following code sample (not by me) to [make a POST request](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the abstract OutputStream class, you might want to use ByteArrayOutputStream which allows you to write a buffer. Even better perhaps would be ObjectOutputStream which would allow you to write string directly since string is serializable. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea I saw this mentioned a few times. But if I'm not mistaken, to initialize the ObjectOutputStream, it would look like this: `ObjectOutputStream oos = ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream output);` which requires an OutputStream... wouldn't my problem remain?